Decidability of Tarski's geometry follows from decidability of real closed fields
I know a proof of decidability for the theory of real closed fields. Now I'm searching for a proof of decidability for Tarski's geometry based on the previous fact. If you know a book where a detailed proof is given could you please give me a reference?

Have you already looked at Tarski's original paper? See for example http://www.geographicknowledge.de/SeminarLFG/Tarski_Whatiselementarygeometry.pdf, Theorem 3, page 23.

I can suggest two open access works; one can follow up the subject taking them as reference:

Tarski's A Decision Method for Elementary Algebra and Geometry
Beeson's "A Constructive Version of Tarski's Geometry."


The first link seems to be broken.

I've fixed it with that of Internet Archive; it's freely downloadable from there, too.
